# Visual Studio 2017 Angular 4 Templates

Tags: angular, visual-studio, spa-template

I am looking for a good Angular 4 template for Visual Studio 2017.  Or what is the best template to use and the way to proceed?  This will be for a Angular 4 SPA web page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`SPA` templates have now been updated for `Angular4`. You can follow [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/) article.

Answer (score 3):

For a barebones Template, independent of backend, and for an overall nice tool to help with Angular 2+ development, look into the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/), as was mentioned in a comment by Vahx.

Specifically for an app starter template, the `ng new` command does the following:

> The Angular CLI makes it easy to create an application that already
>   works, right out of the box. It already follows our best practices!

Once you have a new app, you can then further quickly generate some additional boilerplate / templated code as you progress in development, via the `ng generate` command:

> Generate components, routes, services and pipes with a simple command.
>   The CLI will also create simple test shells for all of these.

Check out the [Angular CLI Docs page](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki) and the main [Angular Getting Started Tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart), for further info.

Although this is not a Visual Studio specific template, it is an option to consider.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a more robust template, I found that the [Emonney QuickApp template](https://github.com/emonney/QuickApp) has some nice features, including login, REST API, EF, boostrap and webpack setup already.

Getting it going wasn't too difficult, just make sure you read the [installation notes](https://github.com/emonney/QuickApp#installation) on their documentation page.

Comment: Thanks for the Emonney link. It's now updated to AspNet Core 2.2 and Angular 8.

Answer (score 0):

Video instructs installing SPA templates for .NET Core project from [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Visual-Studio/Visual-Studio-2017-Launch/WEB-103). It installs different kind of templates like Angular, Knockout, Vue...etc